#WhatWillYouBuild
TLG is putting together an initiative to celebrate the 60th anniversary of the LEGO brick! Many communities, blogs, and review sites will be participating by building creative models and posting to social media using the #WhatWillYouBuild hashtag.
From the Ambassador Network:

We would like to celebrate the 60th Anniversary with you and the AFOL
  Community!
You can build anything – show us your creativity! Build with friends
  or family, include your kids, build with 60 bricks, green bricks or
  whatever comes to your mind – we just want you to be part of the
  celebration!
Take pictures – take many pictures and share on Social Media using the
  #WhatWillYouBuild hashtag.

You can use any parts that you like, but the focus is around the following Classic sets:

10401 Rainbow Fun
10402 Fun Future
10403 World Fun
10404 Ocean’s Bottom
10405 Mission to Mars
40290 60 Years of the LEGO® Brick

TLG has generously offered to provide us with some of those sets, and I plan to put together some alternate models and post them on Rebrickable and elsewhere on social media to build support for both the 60th anniversary and our community. I feel bad that there isn't a good way to "share the wealth" with this opportunity in ways that are easy for traditional LUGs, but hopefully there will be more opportunity for that in the future.
Feel free to share your own designs here and on other social media!

I plan to do this with 10404 in the near future (it's the only set I have from this series). I'm also thinking of writing a review, though I'm not sure where I'll publish it, or if it'll just end up on my blog.

We got our bricks yesterday, and I put a quick model together using the parts from 10405:

I was trying to keep things imaginative and childlike while honoring the history of Lego as these sets do.
Does anyone here have access to post directly to our Twitter account, or is it just a question reposting bot?

It is just a Q posting bot. Contact the team in the TL, I know they changed how the BSE bot worded our questions, so maybe they can do something for you all here.

I wrote a review for 10404 Ocean's Bottom last week, which you can find on my site.
After building the six featured models in the set, there were a large number of pieces left over. I built two custom models: a nudibranch fitted with an engine so it can go faster:

And a sand dollar:


Very cool! Nice work!

I was going to make a conventional set using 10405, but of course my little brother stepped in...

"Who says ducks can't take over the world? Ducks can do anything!"
 - Conspiracy Theorist
 
This is my first post, please tell me if anything needs to be fixed. Kindly, not like this one.
